# Как спарсить остатки на сайте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

Не могу спарсить несколько полей на сайте
https://samara.leroymerlin.ru/product/molotok-slesarnyy-dexter-27-mm-81968476/

Интересуют поля в блоке "Наличие в магазинах":
название магазина 1 - количество
название магазина 2 - количество
название магазина 3 - количество

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

FIND_URL = r'https://samara.leroymerlin.ru/product/molotok-kovanyy-kedr-300-g-1-6-60-055-0300-93834892/'
FAKE_USER = fake_useragent.FakeUserAgent().random

HEADERS = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "User-Agent": FAKE_USER
}


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r
    else:
        print("wrong request")


def get_content(url):
    r = get_html(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    # article = soup.find('div', 'product-info-container')
    article = soup.find('span', {'slot': 'article'}).get_text().strip().split()[1]
    print("Артикл:", article)
    name = soup.find('h1', {'slot': 'title'}).get_text().strip()
    print("Наименование:", name)
    price = soup.find('span', {'slot': 'price'}).get_text().strip()
    print("Цена:", price)

    #stock
    # выдает пустой список
    block_stock = soup.select('.stock-list-content > uc-store-stock:nth-child(1)')
    # и так тоже выдает пустой список
    block_stock =soup.find('div', 'stocks-list-slot-container')
    print(block_stock)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_content(FIND_URL)
```

Кому не сложно обьясните как сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Остатки загружаются отсюда:

```
url = 'https://api.leroymerlin.ru/aem_api/v1/getProductAvailabilityInfo'
```

в заголовке должен быть x-api-key:

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36', 
    'x-api-key': 'VY0AKH3eBwhyGUjBM5U9rO4PyBvTG0cA'
}
```

в payload - Id товара и региона:

```
payload = {
    'productId': '81968476',
    'productSource': 'E-COMMERCE',
    'regionId': '507'  # Самара
}
```

Отправьте POST запрос:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

В ответ получите json примерно такого содержания:

```
{'deliveryModes': {'PICKUP': {'nearestDate': '2021-04-19T16:59:00+04:00', 'minimalPrice': 0, 'maxStockAvailable': 26}, 'HOME_DELIVERY': {'nearestDate': '2021-04-20T09:00:00+04:00', 'minimalPrice': 100, 'maxStockAvailable': 26}}, 'stores': {'9': {'storeName': 'Леруа Мерлен Самара Дыбенко', 'stock': 13, 'sellingScheme': 'GENERAL'}, '13': {'storeName': 'Леруа Мерлен Самара-МЕГА', 'stock': 5, 'sellingScheme': 'GENERAL'}, '34': {'storeName': 'Леруа Мерлен Самара Южное шоссе', 'stock': 26, 'sellingScheme': 'GENERAL'}}, 'warnings': [], 'errors': []}
```

Остатки по магазинам:

```
stores = r.json()['stores']
>>> stores

{'9': {'storeName': 'Леруа Мерлен Самара Дыбенко', 'stock': 13, 'sellingScheme': 'GENERAL'}, '13': {'storeName': 'Леруа Мерлен Самара-МЕГА', 'stock': 5, 'sellingScheme': 'GENERAL'}, '34': {'storeName': 'Леруа Мерлен Самара Южное шоссе', 'stock': 26, 'sellingScheme': 'GENERAL'}}
```

Выводим на печать как-то так:

```
for store in stores.items():
    print(store[1]['storeName'], store[1]['stock'])
```

в итоге:

```
Леруа Мерлен Самара Дыбенко 13
Леруа Мерлен Самара-МЕГА 5
Леруа Мерлен Самара Южное шоссе 26
```

PS `productId`, `regionId` скорее всего где-то в исходном коде страницы, которую вы спарсили get-ом по адресу товарной позиции, `x-api-key` поищите в куках или используйте [session()](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)...

Comment: где можно ознакомиться с информацие, которая поможет мне разобраться с приведенным тобой решении... x-api-key - в session()... это где.. сори за детские вопросы, я начинающий (самоучка)

Comment: @nk.nkt вы нашли  x-api... в r.request.headers т.к. сами его туда и записАли )) по идее, заходя на страницу товара, сайт устанавливает вам куки с заголовком x-api-key, и потом отправляет их в заголовке... для их сохранения удобно использовать [session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) из того же requests